# Angular navigate back without reloading the page

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a page on which the user can apply some filters (through a form) then the user can choose one of the element filtered and go to a detail page.

If the user click back on the detail page is been redirected to the filter page. The filter page is reloaded without keeping the filters data.

I use history.back() function for the back action.

I was wondering if there is a way to navigate back to a page without reloading it showing the exact page that was shown before the user click on details link.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, that your filter-page component gets destroyed on navigate, and therefore the component state will be lost. You have serveral options to maintain the filter state.

- Use [localstorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) to serialize and later retrieve the filterstate
- Use a state management framework like [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) or [ngxs](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/)
- Use a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) to keep the filter state
- Pass the state via [activatedRoute](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-state)

I would suggest to either use the localStorage API to save the state in a serialized way to the browser and retrieve it back on fiter-page init or saving the state of the filter into a service and request the state from there.

Here's a very basic example for the localStorage.
(Not sure if the code is perfectly valid, but you should get the idea..)

```js
export class FilterPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private filterItems: string[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('filterItems'))
      this.filterItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filterItems'));
    } else {
      this.filterItems = [];
    }
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.filterItems.length > 0) {
      localStorage.setItem('filterItems', JSON.stringify(this.filterItems));
    }
  }
  
  addFilterItem(item: string) {
    if (!this.filterItems.includes(item)) {
      this.filterItems = [...this.filterItems, item];
    }
  }
  
  removeFilterItem(item: string) {
    if (this.filterItems.includes(item)) {
      this.filterItems = this.fiterItems.filter(currentItem => currentItem !== item);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this, and got the solution, so posting it for others.

We can make use of `Angular Route Reuse Strategy`.

check the below links

[https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-route-reuse-strategy-b5d40adce841#:~:text=When%20navigating%20away%20from%20a,user%2F57%20for%20example](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-route-reuse-strategy-b5d40adce841#:%7E:text=When%20navigating%20away%20from%20a,user%2F57%20for%20example))

https://medium.com/@rajeshpillai1996/what-is-routereusestrategy-how-to-cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-82da7790cd2b

Answer (score 0):

Navigating from one route to another route will always destroy current component and reload next component. In this case you render detail page from current component only by ngIf . I mean show and hide both template based on search. You will not need to change route, but that’s not a preferred solution.

However I would prefer to save data in common service and use the routing strategy.